# ESP8266 reset problem

Tags: esp8266

I am trying some AT commands with ESP8266 but it resets continously when it stop resetting, i can't get any response from ESP8266.

Example :

```
AT


OK
AT+CWMODE=1


OK
AT+CIPMODE=0


OK
AT+CIPMUX=1


OK
AT+CWJAP="..",".."


 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,1)

wdt reset
load 0x40100000, len 612, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0x12
load 0x3ffe8000, len 788, room 4 
tail 0
chksum 0x50
load 0x3ffe8314, len 264, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x4a
csum 0x4a

2nd boot version : 1.1
  SPI Speed      : 40MHz
  SPI Mode       : QIO
  SPI Flash Size : 4Mbit
jump to run user1

sd
ready

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,1)

wdt reset
load 0x40100000, len 612, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0x12
load 0x3ffe8000, len 788, room 4 
tail 0
chksum 0x50
load 0x3ffe8314, len 264, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x4a
csum 0x4a

2nd boot version : 1.1
  SPI Speed      : 40MHz
  SPI Mode       : QIO
  SPI Flash Size : 4Mbit
jump to run user1

sd
ready
```

I have upgraded my firmware and I tried GPIO0 and GPIO2 are active but it still does not response fine. It worked yesterday but today it is working like crazy..

Comment: What power source are you using?

Comment: Arduino's power source

Comment: Which Arduino?  (if it's not a genuine Arduino please provide a link not just the model).

Comment: It is arduino uno aliexpress clone

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: Arduino için UNO R3 MEGA328P CH340 CH340G UNO R3   USB KABLOSU
 http://s.aliexpress.com/EZNfmaa

Comment: That link doesn't get me anywhere useful.

Comment: Try this please, http://tr.aliexpress.com/item/high-quality-UNO-R3-MEGA328P-CH340-CH340G-for-Arduino-UNO-R3-NO-USB-CABLE/32394695799.html?spm=2114.010208.3.39.Zxfgbq&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_9,searchweb201602_5_10017_10034_10021_507_10022_10020_10018_10019,searchweb201603_7&btsid=2d1749bf-72f9-478f-bfc6-2c8c15b51787

Comment: Wild surmise, because with no schematic or BOM it's impossible to say, but I would guess the 3.3V regulator isn't up to the job. On a genuine Arduino you have 150mA to play with. On that board it's anyone's guess.

Comment: yes . I had the same problem and the capacitor is solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Arduino can not provide enough current for ESP8266 operations. Use external 3.3V power supply, I would recommend 500ma. Also don't forget to put a small cap between vcc and ground. 100uf should do it.

Comment: Okay i will try but why sometimes esp8266 works fine, sometimes doesnt work i cant understand it. Can it be broken too ?

Comment: not likely, in extreme cases yes but its more probable that its current issue . If you can issue AT commands, the module itself is fine. Acording to ESP8266 [power consumption](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=133) chart, in transmit mode it takes +100ma, Arduino 3.3v pin can output about 50ma. So, everything is fine until you try to connect or turn on the wifi radio. At that time there is not enough current for ESP to properly function and it resets. Once reset it once again uses less current and could reboot and present itself as nothing happened. That could be whats misleading you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My esp8266 is powered by FTDI USB to serial module. Since this module can provide a limited amount of current to 3.3V. I use to get frequent reset.

I resolved it by adding a 1000ufd electrolyte capacitor near the power connection of the esp8266 module. And issue resolved like never been there.

I am sure that can also be done by a smaller capacitor. Try with 470 or 220ufd.

enjoy

Rauf